# Get EXIF data from the pic in camera-roll with using Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

environment:

- Worklight v5.0.5
- iOS6

Is there any way to get EXIF data from the photo which retrieve with using Cordova(worklight bundle) Camera API?

seems like Cordova has issues with getting EXIF
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1285

Answer (score 0):

As camera access in Worklight is handled by Cordova, and this is a Cordova bug... this question is actually not Worklight-related. Once a workaround is provided by Cordova, you could freely implement it.

Note that Worklight currently bundles Cordova 2.2 (and 2.3 in the upcoming 5.0.6 release). The fix for this bug is slated for Cordova 2.5 or later...

Comment: I understand it's Cordova bug.  What I am trying to do is to get the photos and the date of taken by default camera-app and use those in Worklight App. Any suggestions to implement the app? Do I have to build own camera plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of the image as a DOM object, Jacob Seidelin has published a pure Javascript EXIF reader:

http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html

This could tie in with the Cordova Camera API which lets you retrieve the image data:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

So, merging those two examples from those pages together, you could end up with something along the lines of:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    alert("Camera make: " + EXIF.getTag(image , "Make"));
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Would that do the trick for you?